# wordpress functions.php how to remove link from featured image

Tags: php, wordpress, image, hyperlink

I notice there are lots of questions regarding removing links from Featured Image in Wordpress. And here's another one which I haven't found an answer to, after days of searching and using trial & error by deleting and modifying the codes.

I would like to remove links that are automatically generated whenever I insert images via Featured Image. As you guessed it, this is done through Portfolio (not Pages or Posts).

I suspect the solution lies within the code below which is extracted from functions.php:

```
// Get Featured Image + Link
    function get_featured_image( $img_size, $fallback ) {
    global $post;       

    $post_hide_featured_single = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_hide_featured_single', true);
    if ( is_single() && $post_hide_featured_single ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {                               
        $featured_image_link_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured_image_link_to', true);
        $featured_image_link_to_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured_image_link_to_url', true);         
        if ( $featured_image_link_to_url ) {
            $featured_image_link = $featured_image_link_to_url;
        }else{
            if ( $featured_image_link_to == 'post' ) {
                $featured_image_link = get_permalink();
            }else if ( $featured_image_link_to == 'image' || !$featured_image_link_to ) {
                $featured_image_link = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
                $featured_image_link = $featured_image_link[0];                 
            }
        } // end if url set         
        $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $img_size, array( 'class' => '' ));
    }else{ // no thumbnail set
        $featured_image_link = get_permalink();
        $featured_image = $fallback;
    } // end if has featured image              

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {       
        return "<div class='post-thumbnail'><a href='" . $featured_image_link . "'>" . $featured_image . "</a></div>";      
    }
```

I have tried deleting the  at the last line, to no avail. I'm thinking maybe its the get_permalink() thing but I am only familiar with html and css.

Any advice or pointers to other resources very highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!
Dave

ADDITIONAL INFO:

Code used to display image in single-portfolio.php is as follows:

```
<div class="grid_8"id="aside">                                      
            <?php

                if ( $portfolio_layout == 'attachment_list' || ! $portfolio_layout ) {

                    $gallery_options = array( 'display' => 'list', 'source' => 'attachment' );                  
                    echo attachment_gallery( $gallery_options );    

                }else if ($portfolio_layout == 'attachment_slider' ){

                    $gallery_options = array( 'display' => 'slider', 'source' => 'attachment' );                    
                    echo attachment_gallery( $gallery_options );    

                }else if ( $portfolio_layout == 'video' ) {

                    // print_r_pre( get_post_custom() );
                    $embed = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_video_src_embed', true );

                    // If video embed source filled in, use it above all others
                    if ( $embed ) {                     
                        echo do_shortcode( $embed );                        
                    }

                }else{                      
                    echo '<!-- template not found -->';                     
                }
            ?>              
            <?php wp_reset_query(); comments_template( '', true ); ?>               
        </div><!--//grid_8-->
```

MORE ADDITIONAL INFO:

Below is the code for attachment_gallery:

```
// Gallery Function (list, gallery, slider, etc...)
function attachment_gallery( $options ) {

    global $post, $wp_query;
    $output = "";

    $original_wp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;

    // Default options, overridden by extract() below if set
    $source = 'attachment';
    $display = 'list';
    $media_size = 'grid_8';
    $slide_effect = '';
    $slide_delay = '';
    $slide_speed = '';
    $slide_nav = '';
    $slide_nav_nextprev = '';

    // Extract options from array to variables
    extract( $options );

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
        'post_type' => $source,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    // Run the new query
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Slider wrap
    if( $display == 'slider' ) { $output .= "<div class='slides_container'>"; }
    $slide_counter = 0;

    $output .= "<ul class='stripped thumbnail-list clearfix'>"; 


    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {            
            the_post();

            if ( $slide_counter > 0 && $display == 'slider' ) { $output .= "<li class='hidden'>"; }else{ $output .= "<li>"; }

                $output .= "<div class='content'>";
                    if ( $source == 'attachment' ) {
                        $post_thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
                        $output .= "<div class='post-thumbnail'><a href='" . $post_thumbnail_src[0] . "'>";
                            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($post->ID, $media_size, false, false);
                        $output .= "</a></div>";
                    }
                    if ( $source == 'slider' || $source == 'post' || $source == 'portfolio' ) {
                        $output .= get_featured_image( $media_size, '' );
                    }
                $output .= "</div><!--//content-->";
```

Comment: `$featured_image_link = get_permalink();` just means that the variable $featured_image_link has been set to the permalink, removing the `<a href='" . $featured_image_link . "'>"` should remove the link. The fact the variable is still being set wouldn't matter, but you could comment it out.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Deleting <a href='" . $featured_image_link . "'>" did not do the trick :(

Comment: The `get_featured_image` code you posted above has nothing to do with your image display. You need to find the `attachment_gallery` function. It's not part of the Wordpress Core. There may be a parameter you can pass to this to control how it outputs the image HTML.

Comment: Dear cpilko, thank you for taking the time to help me out. I have inserted the attachment_gallery code above. Kindly note that I have tried deleting the <a href> from the attachment_gallery but it still doesn't work.